# WebAPI2 - RestSharp - NewtonsoftJson Deserialization crashes at end of content

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, deserialization, restsharp

I have a problem that is driving me crazy. I successfully built a couple of rest services and clients on WebAPI2 using RestSharp. Suddenly I can't get even the simplest of programs (see below) to work. I am currently trying to explicitly use Newtonsoft.JSON to serialize and deserialize. I installed version 7.0.2 of the Json library, which seemed to replace a version 6 supplied by MS in VS2015. I am including all the code below. Note the server appears to be working fine, as verified with Fiddler. I did notice that when I started using the Newtonsoft library, it added escapes on all the '"' which did not occur previously. However the results are the same - it errors off indicating a problem at 1 character more than the indicated "Content-Length".

Note: I am fairly new to C# but have 25+ years on C/C++; I am sure this is something stupid I am missing, but I have been chasing it for about 3 evenings now without any luck. Thanks in advance!

The WebAPI2 config:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace webapi2_server
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}",
                defaults: new {  }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The WebAPI2 controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class my_data
{
    public string sdata { get; set; }
    public int    idata { get; set;  }
}


namespace webapi2_server.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {

        public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            List<my_data> myTestData = new List<my_data>();

            myTestData.Add(new my_data() { sdata = "string1", idata = 1 });
            myTestData.Add(new my_data() { sdata = "string2", idata = 2 });
            myTestData.Add(new my_data() { sdata = "string3", idata = 3 });

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myTestData,     Formatting.Indented);

            return response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json);
        }
    }
}
```

The client software:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;


public class my_data
{
    public string sdata { get; set; }
    public int idata { get; set; }
}

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            RestClient client = new RestClient();
            client.BaseUrl = new Uri("Http://192.168.0.6");

            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.Resource = "test/test";
            request.Method = Method.GET;
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

            List<my_data> my_data_response = new List<my_data>();

            IRestResponse<List<my_data>> response = client.Execute<List<my_data>>(request);

            my_data_response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<my_data>>(response.Content);

            System.Console.WriteLine("Response String: " + response.Content);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Item Count: " + my_data_response.Count() );

        }
    }
}
```

The output from running the client:

Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "[
  {
    "sdata": "string1",
    "idata": 1
  },
  {
    "sdata": "string2",
    "idata": 2
  },
  {
    "sdata": "string3",
    "idata": 3
  }
]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[my_data]'. Path '', line 1, position 205. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[my_data].
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable(Object value, Type initialType, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast(Object initialValue, CultureInfo culture, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Well I have it working now by simply not using Newtonsoft.Json and just using the MS stuff, which is not doing the escaping. However, I have had issues with that as well, which is the reason I tried using the JSOFT to begin with. I had seen comment that the MS serialize had issues with List<>...

It doesn't make sense to me - I would think if I am serializing and deserializing with Newtonsoft, it ought to work...

Not sure this is going to work when I go back to my real world problem, but I will see what happens. If anyone sees a problem as posted, please let me know. Thanks!